# Seeking explanation for a MS SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL function in the database:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split_Using] (@StringToSplit varchar(8000),
@Separator varchar(128))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
  WITH Indices
  AS (SELECT
    0 Start,
    1 Ends
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    Ends,
    CHARINDEX(@Separator, @StringToSplit, Ends) + LEN(@Separator)
  FROM Indices
  WHERE Ends > Start)
  SELECT
    SUBSTRING(@StringToSplit, Start, CASE
      WHEN Ends > LEN(@Separator) THEN Ends - Start - LEN(@Separator)
      ELSE LEN(@StringToSplit) - Start + 1
    END) Id
  FROM Indices
  WHERE Start > 0
```

Even though I already know what it returns (separates a string into chunks, defined by the dividing string, e.g. `Split_Using('a,b,c',',')` would return a table with `('a' 'b' 'c')` I would like to know:

1. Can anyone explain how it does this?
2. Where/how would I find the corresponding documentation (preferably on Microsoft's sites)
3. Is this standard SQL?

Comment: That's a really clever and elegant way of doing this; wish I'd thought of it! It took me a while to work out why it wouldn't return the entire string for the record from the anchor expression, then I saw the `WHERE` clause on the end!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is using a recursive common table expression (CTE). In this case the `WITH Indices` part. The 'anchor' expression is the first part before the `UNION ALL`, the second part refers back to `Indices` recursively.

The MSDN documentation for these is here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I'll just add - recursive CTEs are, to me, one of the most mind-bending concepts in SQL, and never seem to do exactly what you think they are going to do...